How can we determine if a random variable $\limsup _{n\rightarrow \infty } \left( \prod ^{n}_{k=1}X_{k}\right) ^{1/n}$ is measurable?
I would like to prove that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty }Y_n$ is measurable when $Y_n$ is defined as
$$  Y_n = \left( \prod ^{n}_{k=1}X_{k}\right) ^{1/n}  $$
for a sequence of positive random variables $\{ X_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Here, by "measurable", I mean $\mathcal{I}$-measurable, where $\mathcal{I}$ is defined as $\mathcal{I} = \bigcap ^{\infty }_{n=1}\sigma \left( X_{n+1},X_{n+2},\ldots \right) $.
How can I approach this problem ?
It seems plausible to consider $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty }$ as something similar to a $\bigcap ^{\infty }_{n=1}\bigcup ^{\infty }_{k=n}$, but I'm having difficulty understanding how to handle the $\prod_{k=1}^{n}$ part.  I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide guidance on the approach.

For any $m$ we can write  $Y_n=V_mW_m$ where $  V_n = \left( \prod ^{m}_{k=1}X_{k}\right) ^{1/n}  $ and $  W_n = \left( \prod ^{n}_{k=m+1}X_{k}\right) ^{1/n}  $. Since $V_n \to 1$ it follows that $\lim \sup Y_n=\lim \sup W_n$ and  $W_n$
is measurable w.r.t $\sigma (X_{m+1}, X_{m+2},...)$ for each $n$. Hence, $\lim \sup W_n$ is measurable w.r.t.  $\sigma (X_{m+1}, X_{m+2},...)$.
